# My project Android is not compile in the Net Beans

Tags: android, netbeans, compilation

C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:892: The following error occurred while executing this line:

this error show me when i run my project, i don't know why, cause in the eclipse it run with sucess!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude try eclipse or android studio (its getting better and better since Google release it)